# Conditional Inference Forest Variable Importance

Tags: random-forest

This is a cross post of a question i posted several months ago [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/understanding-conditional-inference-forests-variable-importance/57428) on a different forum.

I am trying to understand how variable importance is calculated from the research papers published on the topic. There are two papers to pull this from. The first is [the very math heavy original](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-9-307) paper and [presentation](https://www.statistik.uni-dortmund.de/useR-2008/slides/Strobl+Zeileis.pdf). The [other](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/9387/1/techreport.pdf) is the less math more intuitive treatment and much easier to understand.

The key paragraph from the more intuitive explanation is below

> The set of variables $Z$ to be conditioned on should contain all variables that are correlated with the current variable of interest $X_j$. In the `varimp` function,this is assured by the small default value 0.2 of the threshold argument: By default, all variables whose correlation with $X_j$ meets the condition 1 - ($p$-value) > 0.2 are used for conditioning. A larger value of threshold would have the effect that only those variables that are strongly correlated with $Xj$ would be used for conditioning, but would also lower the computational burden.

The best intuition I have seen from conditional inference trees is [this blog post](https://slcladal.github.io/advancedstatztrees.html#3_conditional_inference_trees) and when I stepped through it, it made instant sense on how the trees work. They stopped short and variable importance :)

My understanding and where it all breaks down:

- In each tree compute the oob-prediction accuracy before the permutation
- For all variables Z to be conditioned on: Extract the cutpoints that split this variable in the current tree and create a grid by means of bisecting the sample space in each cutpoint.
- Within this grid permute the values of X j and compute the oob-prediction accuracy after permutation
- The difference between the prediction accuracy before and after the permutation accuracy again gives the importance of X j for one tree

---

- **My question is where does the variable i want to use go within Z. Is Z determined based on if the correlation is above X amount then permutate the attributes together.**
- **In step 3 what exactly am i permutating within Z? Is this similar to partial correlation?**

---

I think this would make more sense to me if I tried to see Z looks like for a single tree so I ran the code below. Can anyone help?

```
library(party) 
library(janitor) 
library(tidyverse) 
set.seed(123)

# Create a dataframe where we are trying to predict setosa
mydf <- iris %>% 
  mutate(set_tgt = factor(ifelse(Species == 'setosa', 'yes', 'no'))) %>% 
  select(-Species) 

# We will try to predict "set_tgt" 
cf_mod <- cforest(set_tgt ~ ., data = mydf, control = cforest_unbiased(mtry = 2, ntree = 3)) 

# If we use conditional set to true it permutates the variables 
# based on the threshold 
varimp(cf_mod, conditional = TRUE, threshold = 0.2) %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  arrange(desc(value))

# Finding Z 
mod <- ctree(set_tgt ~ .,data = mydf) 
plot(mod)

# Row names are the label we are trying to predict 
Z <- tibble("Petal.Length <= 1.9" = 50, "Petal.Length > 1.9" = 0) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble("Petal.Length <= 1.9" = 0, "Petal.Length > 1.9" = 100)) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  clean_names() 

row.names(Z) <- c("no", "yes") 

# This creates the Z dataframe (maybe), if my understanding isn’t completely wrong
Z
```